# Don't send standard password reset mail and send one programmatically

Tags: 9

I have a script to catch the standard registration mail and send a custom registration mail programatically. The code below is used to stop drupal from sending the standard message.

```
function ccr_subscriptions_mail_alter(&$message)
{
  if ($message['id'] == 'user_register_no_approval_required' && $message['key'] == 'register_no_approval_required') {
    //don't send mail - send custom mail on hook_user_insert
    $message['send'] = FALSE;
    //redirect to homepage and show message
    $response = new RedirectResponse('/?m=r');
    $response->send();
    return;
  }
```

Now I want to do the same for the reset password mail. But I can't figure out what the use $message['id'] is. So I can't stop the standard message from being send.

I tried:

`password_reset`
`user_password_reset`

But they don't seem to work. What is the ID of this message?

Comment: Instead of guessing, can't you just debug with `$message_id = message['id']; \Drupal::logger('mymodule')->info("Mail id: $message_id");` and then trigger the password reset email to be sent?

Comment: good one, I always forget to use the logger. I tried and it didn't log but looking at my logs I figured that I was using the wrong mailaddress and therefor the mail wasn't send at all. The right ID is indeed `user_password_reset` as I suspected.

Comment: Glad you found it.  As a general note, I usually log all custom emails-- this increases the log size a bit, but that gives me an audit trail if mail problems are reported with the server, which can be a big help if something goes wrong.